# Speed of Thousands of Rectangles (with a Stroke!!!) in a WPF Canvas

Tags: wpf, performance, canvas, treemap, stroke

this is my fist question here,

but I didn't find a real answer to my question.

I work on a visualization program and use C# and WPF.

I need to draw a treemap. I actually create Rectangle objects and then add them to the Canvas which works really nice and is very useful, since I also add event handlers to those rectangles (mouse click).

I have a problem with the performance though.
When I add the rectangles and set the Stroke property (SolidColorBrush) the whole process is slowing down extremely. Without those strokes set the speed is ok.

I already improved the performance a little by adding Rectangle objects to a newly created Canvas object and then adding this new Canvas object to the original Canvas object (so not all rectangles are direkt children of the original Canvas, which should help speeding things up).

So my question is how it is possible to add a Stroke to all those Rectangles without breaking the speed.

You can find a comparison of the 'strokeless' and 'stroked' treemap versions in the links.

[Treemap without Strokes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Jaz.jpg)

[Treemap with Strokes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xyksl.jpg)

Thank you very much for your help!

***edit:***

Ok, I have found a solution!

Sorry for writing here first, but I already searched for hours to find a solution but now I found out tht the problem was my used SolidColorBrush!

I have something like this:

```
public static SolidColorBrush TreeMapBorderBrush;
```

And I use this Brush to set the Stroke property of every Rectangle that should be added to the Canvas. But exactly that was the problem.

The code looked like this before:

```
rect.Stroke = Visualization_Helper.TreeMapBorderBrush;
```

I changed it to this now:

```
rect.Stroke = Visualization_Helper.TreeMapBorderBrush.Clone();
```

So I only work with a copy of that Brush on each Rectangle now, which speeds up the processing like there was no Stroke (like in my question)!

Just for your information! Weird!

Comment: I guess you may speed up things even more if you use a frozen brush, by calling its [Freeze](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557735.aspx) method before assigning it to `rect.Stroke`. You could use the same frozen brush instance for all Rectangles.

Comment: Ok thank you, maybe I will try that out today!

Comment: It works for the parts, where I don't need to change the Brush, thank you!